# Tem como fazer um evento após uma impressão em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, bootstrap

Gostaria de fazer uma ação pós impressão, ou seja, só quando o usuário confirmar a impressão que o javascript vai executar um evento programado. Se eu colocar um evento embaixo do `window.print()` o javascript executa mesmo sem o usuário ter imprimido ainda. Algo como:

```
window.print() = function(){
    [...]
}
```

Ouvi falar sobre `matchMedia`, mas não entendi. Teria como exemplificar a partir do código abaixo?

1) Antes da impressão quero o fundo da tela amarelo;

2) Após a impressão quero o fundo da tela verde;

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>teste</title>
  <script>
   function imprimir() {
    window.print()
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="button" value="imprimir" onclick="imprimir()" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei esse trecho de código na [versão em ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325025/how-to-detect-window-print-finish) que parece resolver a questão:

```
(function() {

    var beforePrint = function() {
        console.log('Antes de imprimir...');
    };

    var afterPrint = function() {
        console.log('Depois de imprimir...');
    };

    if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                beforePrint();
            } else {
                afterPrint();
            }
        });
    }

    window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;

}());
```

Maiores detalhes sobre o MatchMedia no autor da questao original [aqui](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/).